# What happens to running alarms when application is updated?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

I need to figure out whether or not to restart that alarm because it's a timed server poll, but there should only be one instance of that alarm.

Comment: I would like to know this too. I checked Android AlarmManager documentation, but couldn't find any useful info. I could always test it on a device and see for myself, but I want some documentation to confirm whether the behavior is consistent across different API levels.

Comment: Hi, did you find answer to this question? Please share if you did.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

Updating your application does nothing to locally stored data, databases,  `PendingIntent`s, notifications, scheduled alarms in the `AlarmManager`, etc. If you have pending alarms when your application is updated, they will still fire at the usual/appropriate times after the updated application is installed.

However, you can always reset your alarm if you feel the need to. Setting an alarm using the `AlarmManager` will discard any previously set alarm that has a matching `PendingIntent`. If you always use the same parameters in the `PendingIntent` then you will never have more than one alarm scheduled.